# Entity framework code first not creating database in vs2010

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

I’m new to vs2010 and the entity framework  (and ASP.NET MVC as well....I’m from a winforms vs2005 background) as well as the azure platform and am starting a project using  these technologies soon. 
I’ve installed vs2010 and the windows azure sdk kit for vs2010 and am running through this tutorial, Deploying an ASP.NET Web Application to a Windows Azure Cloud Service and SQL Database.

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/cloud-service-with-sql-database/

I’ve got as far as the ‘Add SQL support’ section, followed the instructions and when I compile and run no database is being created.
And I’m using sql server 2008 r2.
Any ideas why this is the case? Nothing at all is being shown in the sql server log. My connection details look fine, am I missing some kind of add on or some permission settings need changing?
Cheers,

Comment: mat, please post your connection strings in web.config and app.config

Answer (score -1):

I've sorted this myself. If you wish to know the answers I've posted them in the comments on the tutorial page, just follow the link (names Mathew in the comments section).

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/cloud-service-with-sql-database/

Comment: If you'd like this question to have any value, I suggest you post you answer here as well..